# Find closest element with class name

Tags: jquery, dom

I have a list of unique items with the same class name, .`word`.

```
<ol>
  <!-- a -->
  <li class="word">
    <p>Aloof</p>
    <p>Definition here...</p> 
    <button class="delete-word">Delete</button>     
  </li>

  <!-- b -->
  <li class="word">
    <p>Fallacy</p>
    <p>Definition here...</p> 
    <button class="delete-word">Delete</button>     
  </li>

  <!-- c -->
  <li class="word">
    <p>Disdain</p>
    <p>Definition here...</p> 
    <button class="delete-word">Delete</button>     
  </li>
</ol>
```

I'm using jQuery to display the delete button on mouseover of an element. I'm looking for a way to only display the (closest) button of the hovered `li` element.

I've tried using jQuery's closest() method but unsuccessful.

```
$(document).on("mouseover", ".word", function() {
  // show
  $(".delete-word").show();

  // hide
  $(".word").mouseout(function () {
      $(".delete-word").hide();
  });
});
```

I have a JSBin uploaded, [here](http://jsbin.com/tivaneyeyo/edit?html,js,output).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no reason to be using jQuery (or javascript) for that.  Use CSS:

```css
.delete-word { display:none; }
.word:hover .delete-word {display: block;}
```

```html
<ol>
  <!-- a -->
  <li class="word">
    <p>Aloof</p>
    <p>Definition here...</p> 
    <button class="delete-word">Delete</button>     
  </li>

  <!-- b -->
  <li class="word">
    <p>Fallacy</p>
    <p>Definition here...</p> 
    <button class="delete-word">Delete</button>     
  </li>

  <!-- c -->
  <li class="word">
    <p>Disdain</p>
    <p>Definition here...</p> 
    <button class="delete-word">Delete</button>     
  </li>
</ol>
```

Since it looks like you are generating a list of terms and definitions, you should probably consider replacing your `ol` tag with `dl`, remove your `li` tags (or change to div), change the first `p` tag with `dt` and the second `p` tag with `dd` as this is exactly what these tags are for.

Answer (score 5):

You are not looking for the `closest`, you are looking for a child. Use the `children` method.

```
$(this).children(".delete-word").show();
```

Alternatively, if you wish to select from all descendants of `.word`, you can use the `find` method.

```
$(this).find(".delete-word").show();
```

Note: For a CSS only solution, refer to [Robert McKee's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33702396/find-closest-element-with-class-name#33702532).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are on the right path of thinking, I have ran into this problem a couple times in the last month and asked the same question on here so glad I can finally help someone out with it.

You are looking for the child element no the closest element so you will want to utilize '.children()' but also will need $(this) so you are only grabbing the child of the .word you are hovering over and not all of the .word classes

## Jquery

```
$('.word').hover(function() {
    // show
    $(this).children(".delete-word").show();
  }, function(){
    // callback on mouse out - hide
    $(this).children('.delete-word').hide();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct implementation :

```
$('.word').on("mouseover",function() {
  $(this).find(".delete-word").show();
  }).on("mouseout",function() {
       $(this).find(".delete-word").hide();
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1fe1sanv/2/